# Schwarz reflection principle for arbitrary line

Tags: complex-analysis

My homework problem is to explain in brief conditions for Schwarz reflection principle for arbitrary line $l=a+tb$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Here is my idea:
Let $D$ be an open subset of complex plane symmetric over that line. $D=D^+\cup D^0\cup D^-$ ($D^0 =D\cap l$). Let $f \in H(D^+) \cap C(D^+\cup D^0)$, $f(D^0)\subset D^0$ and $\phi$ a function that reflects $D^+$ to $D^-$ over line. Than analytic continuation is function:

$G=f(z), z\in D^+\cup D^0;$ and  $\phi(f(\phi(z)), z \in D^-$

Is this a good idea?

Comment: Depends. What’s $ϕ$ *exactly*? And what’s $f(D^0) ∈ D^0$ supposed to mean – $f(D^0) ⊂ D^0$? … and you should tell us how you define $D^+$ and $D^-$. … and do you want $D$ to be open or …?

Comment: Yes, I ment to put subset (generalization of condition that f takes real values on real line). $\phi$ is function that reflects $D^+$ over line.

Comment: Now, I am not sure is it important what to take for $D^+$ and what for $D^-$. I think that it is not since as I understand there is no difference between upper and bellow half-plane.

Comment: @user10521 I understand what you mean. But if you reduce describing the conditions to merely saying what things should look like *visually*, the difference in describing the conditions for the Schwarz reflection principle and its generalisation to arbitrary lines vanishes completely. You should ask yourself: How do I describe *symbolically* that $D^+$ lies on *one side* of $l$ and $D^-$ lies on *the other side* (which you didn’t even mention)? Can you give a formula for $ϕ$? That’s the challenge here.

Comment: I didn't understand you completely. Did I make some mistake? And, is it important that $t\in \mathbb{R}$ strictly?

Comment: @k.stm I see what you mean. I think it is possible and I have idea how to do it. Let's say that $D^+$ is "side" that corresponds to upper half-plane when you rotate $l$ to real line with positive angle. And for $\phi$ I will reflect every point on usual way.